# Cant find the "desing view" on stetic (Monodevelop + C#) when i add a new window to my solution

Tags: c#, monodevelop

i'm using monodevelop for C# and i cant find the way to see the "designer" tab that allow me to see the stetic graphical vie of my window.

this happen only when i create a 2nd window. I do see it when i select the mainwindow.cs.

Im new with monodevelop and i'm probably be missing something when i add a new window to my proyect.

is the correct way to add a new window form doing right click on my solution name, then "add" then "new window"?? because that shows only a "newwindow.cs" code but not the stetic view.

thank you so much for your time.

EDIT: i closed monodevelop and i dont know what happened but now the stetic view of the first window doesn't show either.

Comment: MonoDevelop on Linux?

Comment: yes... sorry... ubuntu

Comment: Finally found the solution. Right click on the solution column, over the .cs file... then click on "open with" then "window designer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution. Right click on the solution column, over the .cs file... then click on "open with" then "window designer"